# Laravel update sessions in different database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

We have two databases one is master_client_database and client_database. The default connection is connected to the master_client_database from there it retrieves the client_database configuration based on URL (subdomains). This can be achieved, however the session is stored on master_client_database. Is it possible to store session values on client_database.?

Comment: Why dont you just use another type of session storage, like memcache or redis - then you dont need to worry about switching DB connections.

Comment: The session loads first before it connects to client_database.

Comment: Can't you go to app/config/session.php and set there specific `connection` setting to your client_database connection?